# Givens rotation QR decomposition

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods

I'm trying to create a function that computes the Givens Rotation QR decomposition, following this pseudo-code.

[image]

```
function [Q,R] = givens(A)
[m,n] = size(A);
indexI = zeros(m,n);
indexJ = zeros(m,n);
C = zeros(m,n);
S = zeros(m,n);
for i = 1:n
    for j = i+1:m
        c = A(i,i)/((A(i,i))^2 + (A(j,i)^2))^0.5;
        s = A(j,i)/((A(i,i))^2 + (A(j,i)^2))^0.5;
        A(i,:) = c*A(i,:) + s*A(j,:);
        A(j,:) = -s*A(i,:) + c*A(j,:);
        indexI(j,i) = i;
        indexJ(j,i) = j;
        C(j,i) = c;
        S(j,i) = s;
    end
end
R = A;
Q = eye(m);
for i = 1:n
    for j= j+1:m
        Q(:,i) = c*Q(:,i) + s*Q(:,j);
        Q(:,j) = -s*Q(:,i) + c*Q(:,j);
    end
end
```

However, the R matrix that I get, is not upper triangular. I can't seem to find the mistake here.

Comment: Do you have another reference for that? There are some weird things. `indexI` and `indexJ` are unused. The second `j`loop is almost certainly for `j = i+1:m`, not `j = j+1:m`. I also don't get an upper triangular matrix for `R`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some ambiguity on the slides.

Givens rotation is actually performing matrix multiplication to two rows at a time.

Suppose `[ri;rj]` are your two rows and `Q` is the corresponding givens rotation matirx.

The update is `[ri; rj] = Q*[ri; rj]` but in your code, you update `ri` first and then use the  updated `ri` to immediately update `rj`.

```
    A(i,:) = c*A(i,:) + s*A(j,:);
    A(j,:) = -s*A(i,:) + c*A(j,:);
```

Here is a fix for the error:

```
    tmp = c*A(i,:) + s*A(j,:);
    A(j,:) = -s*A(i,:) + c*A(j,:);
    A(i,:) = tmp;
```